# MS Report Builder, Line Graph, single row of data

Tags: report-builder2.0

I can not seem to get a line graph to draw with a single row of data.

I have a simple row of data that looks like this.

**Title - P1 - P2 - P3 - P4**

BRLI - 100 - 200 - 300 - 400

I can get it to draw if I put each on its own row.

**Title - Value**

BRLI - 100

BRLI - 200

BRLI - 300

BRLI - 400

Any idea what I am missing? I would add pics but this is my first post.

Comment: Your current data does not imply that it is a series and therefore wouldn't make sense as a line chart.  Do you have the ability to make a view/query to translate your data like you just showed?  Otherwise, have you considered using a bar chart to represent the same thing instead?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will consider my options if this is the case. I still feel like I should be able to plot P1-P2-P3-P4.